# pull upload issue (upload from server url) - Vimeo API Php

Tags: php, vimeo-api

I am using vimeo PHP API, Here is the link of API: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

I am facing a issue when i upload video through web url. 
The file is uploading but when i see the video on vimeo. It is saying:
**Invalid file
There was a problem with the file you tried to upload.**

I am using following line of code to send video to vimeo:

```
$lib = new Vimeo($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret'], $config['access_token']);
$response = $lib->request('/me/videos', ['type' => 'pull', 'link' => $videowebpath], 'POST');`
```

$videowebpath is weburl of mp4 file... like http://example.com/video/abx.mp4

If i upload the same file using upload function. It works fine on vimeo also. 
Here is the code:

`$uri = $lib->upload($absolutepath);`

$absolutepath is absolute path of the mp4 file... like 'c:/example.com/video/abc.mp4'

I really want to make it work through pull uploads. Can any one let me know what could be the issue?

Comment: 1. add examples of what are `$videwebpath`, `$absolutepath`  2. are You video files downloadable from outside?  3. put full code of how You do upload - calling `$lib->request` does not mean anything to me at all.

Comment: well there maybe 2 issues: 1. file cannot be accessible (maybe some network restrictions), 2. file codec is not supported or some other issues of transcoding video. Lets test using different video and different host. Can I ask You to call pull request for this url: http://anarjafarov.me/SMLS-PROMO-EN.mp4   ?

Comment: @num8er.. thanks for your reply.. video is accessible in browser... let me try this video.. by the way, same video is working fine when I upload through upload function..

Comment: it is working for this... i think, some thing with trans coding. i am using video js recorder to record video. I think, i should use ffmpeg, and try the video after transcoding

Comment: Does the same video file work when uploading via https://vimeo.com/upload? You'll want to contact Vimeo Support and provide the link value you're using so Vimeo can troubleshoot: https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: @TommyPenner. yes, that worked when i upload via vimeo.com/upload. :(
Ok i connect with the support.